# How can I perform a thread-safe get then remove with ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

In an interview, I was asked to check whether following code works as intended.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

if (chm.get(key) != null) {
    chm.get(key).doSomething();
    chm.remove(key);
}
```

According to JavaDocs, `get` returns value of last completed update operation. So if thread 1 already called `chm.remove(key)` and if thread 2 came inside the if statement and is about to call `get` method then we might get an exception. Is this correct?

How can I make this thread-safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. If this `Map` can be modified by multiple threads, it's possible that the first call to `chm.get(key)` will return a non-null value and the second call will return `null` (due to the removal of the key from the `Map` done by another thread), and thus `chm.get(key).doSomething()` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

You can make this code thread safe by using the local variable to store the result of `chm.get(key)`:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Integer value = chm.get(key);

if(value != null) {
    value.doSomething(); // P.S. Integer class doesn't have a doSomething() method
                         // but I guess this is just an example of calling some arbitrary 
                         // instance method
    chm.remove(key);
}
```

BTW, even if that `Map` wasn't a `ConcurentHashMap` and only one thread had access to it, I'd still use a local variable, since it's more efficient than calling the `get()` method twice.

EDIT :

As commented below, this fix will not prevent `doSomething()` from being called multiple times for the same key/value by different threads. Whether or not that's the desired behavior is not clear.

If you wish to prevent the possiblity of `doSomething()` being called by multiple threads for the same key/value, you can use `chm.remove(key)` for both removing the key and obtaining the value at the same step.

This however runs the risk that `doSomething()` will not be executed at all for some key/value, since if the first call to `doSomething()` resulted in an exception, there won't be another call to `doSomething()` by another thread, since the key/value pair will no longer be in the `Map`. On the other hand, if you remove the key/value pair from the Map only after `doSomething()` executes succesfully, you guarantee that `doSomething()` is executed successfuly at least once for all the key/value pairs that were reomved from the `Map`.

Comment: Probably be even better to just write `Integer value = chm.remove(key);`, and remove the existing `chm.remove(key);` line entirely. That way the `value` isn't lying around in the map while you're invoking `doSomething()`.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I don't know if it's a problem that the value is `lying around in the map while you're invoking doSomething()`. Perhaps the requirement is to remove the key/value entry from the Map only after `doSomething` is executed successfully.

Comment: This is not Threadsafe, `doSomething` can be called more than once.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. and that can be desired or not. We don't know.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Yes, `doSomething` may be called more than once, but it's not necessarily a problem. My code fixes the exception that the original snippet may cause. Whether or not `doSomething` should be prevented from being called twice for the same key/value depends on the specific use case.

Answer (score 19):

`Map.remove(key)` returns the value if it has been removed. This is a very good trick in many situations, including yours:

```
Object value = chm.remove(key)
if(value != null)
{
     value.doSomething();
}
```

You can't work safely with a get then a remove because if two threads call your method at the same time, there's always a risk they call `doSomething` two or more times, before the key has been removed.

This is not possible if you remove it first. The code above is Threadsafe, also simpler.

Comment: Somehow I feel like the interviewer would expect this as a right answer